# Change php error reporting to hide warnings for specific site only [Debian|Ubuntu]

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

Imagine a couple of `sites-enabled` available from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. (Only Debian-based distros work like this.)

Is it possible to mute `warning` messages from php scripts from *a specific site*, without touching the actual `htdocs`?

Normally there are a couple of solutions to achieve someting related:

1. Add an `error_reporting()` directive e.g. `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` to the scripts executed.
2. Set php_flags in `.htaccess` files like so: `php_flag display_errors off`
3. Use `ini_set` inside scripts:

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 'Off');
   error_reporting(0);
   ```
4. Prepend `@` to functions that throw warnings or errors.
5. Change `php.ini` to actually say
   `error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_WARNING`
   `display_errors  = 1`

However, these all mean touching the htdocs or having the change applied globally. Imagine the `htdocs` are mounted read-only. How would I suppress warnings (or notices) for certain sites only?

I am assuming Debian/Ubuntu has `a2ensite` specific configurations for a reason and I am hoping I can alter those. There is a `log_level` directive in the example 'site available' configuration, but this handles the amount of messages logged. Not the messages output by the php scripts.

Manually adding sections in `php.ini` or `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf` will also work. If it is possible.

See also:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have access to the apache vhost configurations, of course you can also use php_flag directives inside a Virtual Host in the sites-available directory. This way, they're only applied to this vhost.

Add something like this inside your Virtual Host:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_admin_flag display_errors off
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want only actual errors displayed, you can use the php directive `error_reporting` with an integer value that describes the types of error levels you want to be displayed:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_admin_flag display_errors on
    php_admin_value error_reporting 22517
</IfModule>
```

This is equivalent to a setting of

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED;
```

in php.ini. More possible values for example here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20131009000719/http://www.websitefactors.co.uk/php/2013/01/php-error-reporting-settings

Error reporting value calculator:

http://www.bx.com.au/tools/ultimate-php-error-reporting-wizard

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. The vhost configuration is site-specific and inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Do you know any trickery to change this so that errors are in fact displayed, but warnings are not?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: This is [Thrift Shop] awesome! Accepted.

Comment: You can also calculate the number just by running this in the command line: `php -r 'echo E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED; echo "\n";'`

Answer (score 1):

I added :

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
 php_admin_flag display_errors on
 php_admin_value error_reporting 30711
</IfModule>
```

to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/work and thats working just fine.

Yes I know I should fix those notices, but I'm working on a old script, and will need to come back to that, for now this has solved my problem, and was what the op was looking for. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of 30711?  I assume this is an or'ed bitmask of the E_* error reporting constants.  If so, it's horrible practice to write it as you did.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman - The constants E_* are only available *within*  php, and apache doesn't know what they are. 

See "Note: PHP Constants outside of PHP" 
 on http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without .htaccess or applying the configuration globally. Apache cannot "see" files outside its root folder (htdocs) and .htaccess files only work when in the site's folder. php_flag doesn't function outside of .htaccess, either.

So basically, it's not possible to do on a site-by-site basis without *some* modification or an .htaccess file.

Comment: Actually, Apache knows exactly what site we are talking about because we can specify sections for specific directories in the configuration. The answer by etagenklo is close to doing just that. :) Just need to find a way to alter it so it applies to warnings.